# Programmatically (e.g. in Python) adding clipping to an audio file?

Tags: audio, python

I am trying to replicate the audio artifact exemplified [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXptusF7Puo) to a set of 1000 audio files. In particular, I would like to be able to 'clip' the louder parts of each sound clip so they become distorted as in this video. Is there a way I can do this with a script?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions requesting working code written to a specification are off-topic as they are unlikely to benefit anyone else. Instead, describe the problem you're solving and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Simple clipping :
threshold = 0.5
If x > threshold
  x = threshold
elseif x < -threshold
  x = -threshold
end

Real-world clipping can be significantly more complex than this, involving various time-constants, asymmetry, heating-effects,....